# MapServer Not Logging to MS_ERRORFILE

Tags: mapserver, debugging, iis

I'm attempting to debug a 500 server error with my MapServer (running as a FastCGI on IIS 7.5). This would be much less challenging if I could get some indication of where the failure is happening, but MapServer seems disinclined to log anything. I also have no logs in Event Viewer related to the failure so I'm at a loss.

MapServer was configured as documented [here](https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/wiki/Installing-Mapserver-under-IIS-7.n-with-FastCGI). And the map file I'm using is below:

```
MAP
  NAME           benchmark
  IMAGETYPE      PNG
  EXTENT         -106.39 25.50 -93.31 36.30
  SIZE           400 300
  IMAGECOLOR     255 255 255

  CONFIG "PROJ_LIB" "/MapServer/proj/nad"
  CONFIG "MS_ERRORFILE" "/MapServer/tmp/ms_error.txt"
  DEBUG 3

  WEB
    METADATA
      "ows_enable_request"   "*"
      "wms_title"           "Lonestar Benchmark"
      "wms_onlineresource"  "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/MapServer/benchmark.map&"
      "wms_srs"             "EPSG:4269 EPSG:4326"
    END
  END

  PROJECTION
     AUTO
  END

  LAYER # States polygon layer begins here
    NAME         ngs_tx
    DATA         "/MapServer/data/tx.shp"
    STATUS       DEFAULT
    TYPE         POLYGON

    CLASS
      NAME       "TX NGS Survey Data"

      STYLE
        COLOR        232 232 232
        OUTLINECOLOR 32 32 32
      END
    END
  END
END
```

The log directory and file already exist (I first tried without them existing and then created the directory and file after that didn't work). Also, I've tried using "C:" prefixed paths with no difference in behavior.

The CGI is currently set to "connect as" the Administrator, so it can't be a permissions issue. (And yes, this is highly insecure. This is a test environment so doesn't matter.)

Comment: HTTP 500 errors tend to happen before MapServer is ready for logging. Does you get any answer from `http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe`?

Comment: Ah-ha! Yes, that gives me much more detail. Now I get "Can not log on locally to C:\MapServer\cgi-bin as user localhost\administrator with virtual directory password". I can work with that.